# FM radio application in android development

Tags: android, fm-radio

I want to develop FM radio applicaiton . But FM radio application api is depend on devices. Is there any idea for develop general FM application for all general devices? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no general API for FM radio on Android, because every supplier uses their owen radio chipset. Worst of all, the last Google phone is shipped with no radio at all, which gives little possibilities that there will ever be a native FM radio API by Android itself.

The only project that manage to get close into supporting all devices is [Spirit FM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=34526627&postcount=4882), which unfortunately is available as an App and does not offer an open API, but you may try to have some co-operation if you contact them.

Another future option may be the "Euro-Chip" [which is being pushed by the European Broadcasting Union](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http://radiomagonline.com/digital_radio/ebu_stresses_importance_of_euro-chip_1115/&ei=Q9q8UJWnCI7KtAaV0YC4Ag&usg=AFQjCNFNCTI2HxHxyiU30Z4hugn4gvHIgw), which will for sure have a standard API. But it will take quite some time until this gets broadly into the market, if it ever manages to.